# How can I send a file from an iPhone to my server?

Tags: ios, sql-server, vb.net, file-upload, ftp

I've seen lots of questions and answers about this topic, but unfortunately none of them seem to fit my needs closely enough. This question is about both iOS and vb2010.

I have created an app which communicates with my server (at this point, "my server" is actually my Win7 machine that I am using for development. Eventually it will move to an actual server). The back end is a VB program that interfaces between the iPhone app and a SQL Server database. A specific port is open to the computer, and everything there works great. I am able to retrieve data from the database and display it on the iPhone with the app, and also able to save records from the app to the database. It's all so very cool, and I'm really jazzed about it.

The final phase of the project requires uploading a camera image to the server. This is the part where it gets funky for me.

So far I have been able to save the image as a file on the iPhone's disk. Now I need to understand better how to transfer that file to a directory on the server.

I know that there are many techniques that use the "post" method, but as I understand it, that requires a PHP or ASP page to accomplish. FTP generally uses ports 20 and 21. What I would really like is to be able to set up the existing software to receive an upload request from the app, and then place itself in receive mode. This would not require opening another port, and I can tailor the VB code to handle the file however I like.

All I really need to understand is, how can I get the two programs to do the file transfer? And is it reasonable to assume that I can use the same port?

Comment: is your app going to be over the web accessing this server or is this just within a local network?

Comment: The app works either way. We have set up a url specifically for this server, so whether it comes by 4G or wifi, it still knows where to go. However, most of the users will be using 4G, since they are spread out all over the southwest.

Comment: yeah, you're going to need to build a web service api, I would use ASP.NET's new WebApi framework.  It's relatively easy to get an api built up and deployed.  That web api/service will have to then marshal the image data to the server/db.  The iphone app will simply make calls to the api.

Comment: Yeah, that looks hopeful. I'll study it and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Still having trouble. I know better what I need, just don't know how to get there. For that reason, I am going to start a new thread with clarifications and more specifics.